# Close Twitter tab after tweet - mobile

Tags: twitter

Is there a way to close a Twitter tab/window after a successful tweet on mobile? I need it to close a) to go back to my site b) to record the callback

When I use the following it works perfectly on a desktop device, the Twitter window closes when tweet is sent, but on mobile it does not.

I will add that I do a similar thing for Facebook and it works perfectly and closes itself after a successful post.

Here's what I'm using:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=&amp;url=http://m.myURL.com" target="_blank">Tweet</a>

// twitter set up
window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

// twitter callback
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
  twttr.events.bind('tweet', function (event) {
    console.log("Tweet successful");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer to this so posting in case anyone has same problem.

The answer is you can't (as of 24th March 2015), it's a few different forces at work preventing it apparently.

[More information here from Twitter](https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-events-bind-follow-not-firing-on-mobile-web-browser/20122/10)